# log4j2 RolllingFileAppender filePattern create a wrong date

Tags: log4j2

I used date in filePattern, but the date log4j create is not right.
Today is 2015-11-23, but log4j create a file directory named 2015-12.
my log4j2 version is 2.4.1.
[here is a snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCImI.png)

below is my log4j2 configuration.

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/executor.log" append="true"
                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/executor-%d{yyyy--MM--dd}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%t  %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c %p -%m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="24" modulate="true"/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1MB"/>
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue is due to your intervals.   Its effectively setting up the initial rollover file to be when the *end* of the next rollover would be.  The documentation on the [RollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) for the *TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy* says: "How often a rollover should occur based on the **most specific time unit** in the date pattern."  Since your most specific time unit is dd, or day of month, its setting it up for 24 days from 2015-11-23, or sometime in month 12, when it would rollover.

What you probably want is an interval of 1. This should rollover each file day and then once a month spills over, it would into the next subfolder because 1 day was triggered.

I've tested this with your pattern, but use a MM at the end and and a interval="24." Modulated, it rolled into 12/2016, but not modulated, it rolled over saying 11/2017! I can't say why and per my comment above, there have been issues with this feature reported.

Answer (score -1):

Have same problem.

```
<RollingFile name="DailyFileAppender" fileName="logs/server.log"
                 filePattern="logs/server - %d{yyyy-MM-dd} - %i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="5"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 KB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
    </RollingFile>
```

The output file's data is wrong. example the date is "2015-12-01" the output date is "2015-12-05"

Comment: Remove <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="24" modulate="true"/> it work fine.

Comment: I changed filePattern to  filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/executor-%d{yyyy--MM--dd}-%i.log.gz">

Comment: above comments is not right, I changed filePattern to  filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/executor-%d{HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz">

Comment: @TinyZ suggestion worked for me, although I don't understand why. There is a bug, [LOG4J2-116](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-116), that seems similar to our issue.